# Consulta SQL GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

¿Por qué motivo no funciona ordenar grupos por fechas? He visto que se puede solucionar con una subconsulta pero si hay otra alternativa directa. Gracias por la ayuda.

```
SELECT fecha as date,SUM(importe) as importe FROM reservas WHERE fecha  <= '2021-09-25' AND fecha > '2021-08-23' GROUP BY fecha ASC;
```

Comment: Por que una cosa es agrupar: `GROUP BY .....` y otra ordenar que sería: `ORDER BY .......`, trata de separar ambas instrucciones y prueba de nuevo tu query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad es un error en la consulta, `ASC` no es una cláusula de `GROUP BY` si no de `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT fecha as date, SUM(importe) as importe 
FROM reservas 
WHERE fecha  <= '2021-09-25' AND fecha > '2021-08-23' 
GROUP BY fecha
ORDER BY Fecha;
```